# Does having the same `require` in multiple files increase runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm planning to separate my functions into separate files and then import them into a single `index.js` which then becomes the main exporter. So I'm wondering if having something like `var bcrypt = require('bcrypt')` in several of my files be slower than just having it in one file.

Here's how I'm planning to group and export in index.js

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path')
const modules = {}

const files = fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
files.forEach(file => {
    if (file === 'index.js') return
    let temp = require(path.join(__dirname, file))

    for (let key in temp) {
        modules[key] = temp[key]
    }
});
module.exports = modules
```

As an example of what I mean:

file1.js

```
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

module.exports.file1test = "hi"
```

file2.js

```
var bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

module.exports.file2test = "bye"
```

Comment: As compared to what alternative? The answer is correct that it is not significantly slower and that it is cached, but it is likely slower than inlined duplicate code for example. Still, you shouldn't worry about it

Comment: @AluanHaddad alternative is to separate the file as little as possible. So instead of having file1, file2, just have file, which does the `require` once and then create all functions/variables in that file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it does not. Whenever a module is `require`d for the first time, the module's code runs, assigns something to its exports, and those exports are returned. Further `require`s of that module simply reference those exports again. The logic is similar to this:

```
const importModule = (() => {
  const exports = {};
  return (name) => {
    if (!exports[name]) exports[name] = runModule(name);
    return exports[name];
  };
})();
```

So, multiple `import`s of the same module is no more expensive than referencing an object multiple times.

Comment: ah, that's good to know. Now I can separate my code without worry